# Merging Two Files Columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to add 6 field of File2 in last field of File1, i'm using following command but unable to get output.

`awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$6; next} {print $0,a[$1]}' File2 File1`

File1:

```
zehriscollection.co.uk,IPAddress,hqfmqxvm,noor82@gmail.com,2015-06-06 16:34,home,8000,4,Professional Linux Based,paper_lantern,root,Hostname,1433590496,4212,8192000
zindagidesire.com,IPAddress,hgchcjhcj,saeed@gmail.com,2015-08-19 18:16,home,8000,107,Professional Linux Based,paper_lantern,root,Hostname,1439990214,110126,8192000
zobasra.co.uk,IPAddress,egranius,"donot@hotmail.com, w@live.com",2013-11-30 19:07,home,3072,4,Standard,x3,root,Hostname,1385820470,4208,3145728
```

File2:

```
zehriscollection.co.uk        hqfmqxvm         Usage:  4.02M      Inodes:  275
zindagidesire.com             hgchcjhcj        Usage:  107.19M    Inodes:  4765
zobasra.co.uk                 egranius         Usage:  4.02M      Inodes:  390
```

What i want to get:

```
zehriscollection.co.uk,IPAddress,hqfmqxvm,noor82@gmail.com,2015-06-06 16:34,home,8000,4,Professional Linux Based,paper_lantern,root,Hostname,1433590496,4212,8192000,275
zindagidesire.com,IPAddress,hgchcjhcj,saeed@gmail.com,2015-08-19 18:16,home,8000,107,Professional Linux Based,paper_lantern,root,Hostname,1439990214,110126,8192000,4765
zobasra.co.uk,IPAddress,egranius,"donot@hotmail.com, w@live.com",2013-11-30 19:07,home,3072,4,Standard,x3,root,Hostname,1385820470,4208,3145728,390
```

Answer (score 2):

This does the job:

```
awk '{print $6}' File2 | paste -d ',' File1 -
```

The `-` at the end is the standard input that's piped in from awk.

EDIT: When you need to make sure, that the domain names match in the files, you can do it with `join` instead of `paste`.

For example like this:

```
sort File2 | awk '{print $1,",",$6}' | sed 's/ //g' | join -t ',' File1 -
```

Comment: FYI, when I tested this, I had to remove the additional whitespaces at the end of the lines of File1.

Comment: If the file2 contains random domains than it doesn't put the valid fields against each domain.

Comment: @rlinux57 I edited my answer to include an example that worked for me when not all domain names match.

Comment: Why you use `join -t ',' File1 -` could you explain a bit ?

Comment: The `-t` switch specifies the character to use as input and output field separator. This can't be specified separately, unfortunately. That's why I included the `,` in the awk script as well and removed the additional spaces created by awk. Actually I have no clue about awk. There might be a more elegant way to do this. Anyway, the `-t ','` is just, so that the fields are separated in the result as you wish. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: My file1 and file2 lines are 742, when i run `sort File2 | awk '{print $1,",",$6}' | sed 's/ //g' | join -t ',' File1 -` command, it shows only 540 lines record, It should be 742.

Comment: Then some domains don't match exactly. Maybe what you want is approach 1, with `paste`, but sort both files before?

Comment: the approach that i'm using is `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$6; next} {print $0,a[$1]}' File2 File1` but it only works on if file1 doesn't have "," delimeter.

Answer (score 1):

One way using the `split` function:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$6; next}
{split($0, b, ","); u=b[1]; if (u in a) {$0=$0","a[u]}}
1' file2 file1
```

It saves 6th field from `file2` in `a[1st field]` then for each line of `file1` it splits it on comma into array `b` and assigns the first element `b[1]` to `u`. If `u` is in `a` it appends a comma and `a[u]` to the line. The final `1` prints each line of `file1` whether it was modified or not.